# wp_ajax_nopriv not working for logged out users

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

For the record I searched through every other time this was asked but could not find the solution

I'm simply trying to add ajax content to a page for logged out users and failing dispite using wp_ajax_nopriv. I've tried deactivating all plugins and that didn't help. Although I do want to lock down access to the backend admin solely to the admin, I do not currently have that implemented.

Loading the script

```
function html5blank_header_scripts()
{
    if ($GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php' && !is_admin()) {

        wp_register_script('globalJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/global.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('globalJs'); // Enqueue it!

        wp_localize_script(
            'globalJs', 
            'ajax_object', 
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) 
        );
    }
}
```

PHP ajax function

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_new_ajax_event_template', 'new_ajax_event_template' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_new_ajax_event_template', 'new_ajax_event_template' );

function new_ajax_event_template() {
    global $post;
    $postID = $_POST["post_id"];
    $post = get_post($postID);
    <------- lots of stuff that works for logged in user ----->
    die();
}
```

JQuery ajax script

```
$(document).on("click", ".title[data-ajax='post']", function() {
    $post_id = $(this).data("id");
    $post_type = $(this).data("type");
    $post_url = $(this).data("url");
    var historyData = $(".wrapper").attr("data-history");
    if (!historyData){
        historyData = [];
    }
    else{
        historyData = JSON.parse(historyData);
    }
    historyData.push({
      id: $post_id,
      type: $post_type,
      url: $post_url
    });
    var data = {
        action : 'new_ajax_'+ $post_type +'_template',
        post_id : $post_id
    };
    $("#main").empty().hide();
    $.ajax({
        url : ajax_object.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : data,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#main").append(html);
            history.pushState('data', '', $post_url);
            $(".wrapper").attr("data-id", $post_id);
            $(".wrapper").attr("data-history", JSON.stringify(historyData));
            $("#main").fadeIn("fast");
        }
    });
});
```

This is all works perfectly for logged in users but fails for logged in users and I have no idea why. There's nothing in the functions.php that should prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by making sure admin-ajax.php was setup in the head

```
add_action('wp_head', 'plugin_set_ajax_url');
function plugin_set_ajax_url() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ajax_object = {};
        ajax_object.ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below scenario, I could not say surely

1) Did you get jQuery error?, check in browser console and if have anything clear it.

2) Check admin-ajax.php response in browser developer tool -> network (PFA)

[image]